# How to share image on facebook and twitter using meta content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, twitter, koala

I want to share image and content on facebook and twitter in rails like that

[image]
I saw code for that

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@gorails" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="<%= yield :title %>" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="<%= yield :meta_description %>" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="<%= asset_url "open-graph.jpg" %>" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@excid3" />
```

but not know how to integrate that. my purpose is just to share image on facebook, twitter

Comment: You can try to use this gem https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button

Comment: this gem not allow to share images

Comment: meanz no customization

Answer (score 0):

for facebook, check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

for twitter, this might be helpful https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary

Comment: how i need to add facebook button?